# Base64 decoding photo error, getting some unusual text instead of real photo

Tags: android, vcf-vcard, google-pixel

I've tried to import vCard info into Google Pixel phone (.vcf file). On every other phone (Samsung, Huawei, any Android or IOS phone) there is no problem at all with all information, only with Google Pixel phone. What i have when i import the .vcf file is some unusual text instead of photo. You could see the attachment. Please help how to resolve this issue.

[image]